Rails Turbo + Stimulus can't get FrameElement [solved]
I have a stimulus controller and a turbo frame. Based on the documentation, I should be able to reload the frame since it is part of the FrameElement API.
Every on change event has the following error:
frame.reload is not a function

For some reason my querySelector gets an object, but it is not a FrameElement. Any help?
Template:
    <%=turbo_frame_tag "frame_id", src: my_path do%>
      <%=render '....'%>
    <% end %>

Stimulus Controller:
    const frame = document.querySelector('turbo-frame#frame_id');
    frame.reload();


It turns out I didn't actually import turbo. Oops.
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"

